# I keep getting the index out of range error

Tags: python, list

I basically have words from a dictionary with their definition. However I only need to extract the word. What I did was made them a list and only extracted the first index however I still get an index error.

```
rps=open('rootsPrefixesSuffixesnew.txt','r')
rpsnew=open('wordsonly.txt','w')
for words in rps:
    words=words.strip()
    words=words.split()
    words1=list(words)
    print words1[0]

rps.close()
rpsnew.close()
```

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Please include the code which was used to access the array

Comment: hey.. i pasted the code here but the format gets messed up. sorry about that as its the first time i am  using this site.

Comment: i typed [0]. thats when it gives me the error

Comment: the list may not be well behaved. you get an index error if there is no output from the split action. Catch the exception or build other logic to check if there are any results.

Comment: What's the content in `rootsPrefixesSuffixesnew.txt`? Your list here in `words1=list(words)` could be empty.

Comment: ok basically this text file consists of roots, prefixes and suffixes. My task is to compare it to another text file which has many words and count how many roots, prefixes and suffixes are there. For example the root 'dict' will read 100 which means there are 100 words which have the root 'dict'.

Answer (score 2):

The only place you're "indexing" and could get an "index error" is the `print words1[0]` line (you should of course in the question supply information about which line you got the error on - that's written in the error message).

This error is expected if a line in the file does not contain any words, for example an empty line. Note that if the last line ends with a newline there's an empty line at the end of the file. Of course you should also supply an example of your input data as well.

To fix this we could for example check the length of the `words1` array, if there's no words on the line the length of the array (ie the number of words) will be zero:

```
rps=open('rootsPrefixesSuffixesnew.txt','r')
rpsnew=open('wordsonly.txt','w')
for words in rps:
    words=words.strip()
    words=words.split()
    words1=list(words)
    if len(words1) == 0:
        continue
    print words1[0]

rps.close()
rpsnew.close()
```

Then of course if you want to put the words in `wordsonly.txt` you should use print chevron when printing (ie `print >>rpsnew, words1[0]`), this means the same as `print` except that the output is put into the (opened) file after the chevron. Also you shouldn't have to copy the `words` it's already a list so the solution could be:

```
rps=open('rootsPrefixesSuffixesnew.txt','r')
rpsnew=open('wordsonly.txt','w')
for words in rps:
    words=words.strip()
    words=words.split()
    if len(words) == 0:
        continue
    print >>rpsnew, words[0]

rps.close()
rpsnew.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! however could you explain why did you use the len function here? and why did you use the code >>rpsnew? is this another way of writing into a new file?

Comment: @azon333 I've updated my answer and I hope it's clearer now. Normally `print` prints to the screen, the `>>rpsnew` makes it print to `rpsnew` instead.

Comment: thanks! i finally get that :) Could you explain the len function though..as in why do we use len(words)==0?